# UITableView content inset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want my cells to start from an offset from the top. I tried using

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(150,0,0,0)];
```

but get a black bar instead.[image]

[image: with inset]

Comment: r u using autolayout

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder or creating the TableView in code? Is there any place in the code where you manipulate the frame of the TableView itself?

Comment: I have some constraints set. Also I am using Prototype cells from Storyboard